# Deep Smote error : RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (51200x1 and 512x300)

Tags: pytorch, smote

I am trying to run deep Smote on cifar10 and Dont have much experience with pytorch as I code in tensorflow. It works fine when I run it on MNIST and FMNIST keeping channles = 1 there
However, the moment i try it on cifar10, i dosent behave well.
The code given in the paper says that it works for Cifar10 too,
All the help is appreciated
Here is the link to the source code of the paper
https://github.com/dd1github/DeepSMOTE
The source code is in Tensorflow, can someone pls help me here

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\RESEAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_24844/1514724550.py in <module>
     93 
     94                 # run images
---> 95                 z_hat = encoder(images)
     96 
     97                 x_hat = decoder(z_hat) #decoder outputs tanh

~\.conda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []



~\.conda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1846     if has_torch_function_variadic(input, weight, bias):
   1847         return handle_torch_function(linear, (input, weight, bias), input, weight, bias=bias)
-> 1848     return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
   1849 
   1850 

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (51200x1 and 512x300)
```

Here's the code :

```
## create encoder model and decoder model
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()

        self.n_channel = args['n_channel']
        self.dim_h = args['dim_h']
        self.n_z = args['n_z']
        
        # convolutional filters, work excellent with image data
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(self.n_channel, self.dim_h, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            #nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(self.dim_h, self.dim_h * 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(self.dim_h * 2),
            #nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(self.dim_h * 2, self.dim_h * 4, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(self.dim_h * 4),
            #nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            
            
#             nn.Conv2d(self.dim_h * 4, self.dim_h * 8, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            
            #3d and 32 by 32
            nn.Conv2d(self.dim_h * 4, self.dim_h * 8, 4, 1, 0, bias=False),
            
            nn.BatchNorm2d(self.dim_h * 8), # 40 X 8 = 320
            #nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True) )#,
            #nn.Conv2d(self.dim_h * 8, 1, 2, 1, 0, bias=False))
            #nn.Conv2d(self.dim_h * 8, 1, 4, 1, 0, bias=False))
        # final layer is fully connected
        print("linearer >>>>>>>> ",self.dim_h * (2 ** 3), self.n_z)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(self.dim_h * (2 ** 3), self.n_z)
        print("leeeeeeeeeee ")
        

    def forward(self, x):
        #print('enc')
        #print('input ',x.size()) #torch.Size([100, 3,32,32])
        x = self.conv(x)
        
#         x = x.squeeze()
#         print('aft squeeze ',x.size()) #torch.Size([128, 320])
        #aft squeeze  torch.Size([100, 320])
        x = self.fc(x)
        #print('out ',x.size()) #torch.Size([128, 20])
        #out  torch.Size([100, 300])
        return x


class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()

        self.n_channel = args['n_channel']
        self.dim_h = args['dim_h']
        self.n_z = args['n_z']

        # first layer is fully connected
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.n_z, self.dim_h * 8 * 7 * 7),
            nn.ReLU())

        # deconvolutional filters, essentially inverse of convolutional filters
        self.deconv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(self.dim_h * 8, self.dim_h * 4, 4),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(self.dim_h * 4),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(self.dim_h * 4, self.dim_h * 2, 4),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(self.dim_h * 2),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(self.dim_h * 2, 1, 4, stride=2),
            #nn.Sigmoid())
            nn.Tanh())

    def forward(self, x):
        #print('dec')
        #print('input ',x.size())
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = x.view(-1, self.dim_h * 8, 7, 7)
        x = self.deconv(x)
        return x
```

..........

```
#NOTE: Download the training ('.../0_trn_img.txt') and label files 
# ('.../0_trn_lab.txt').  Place the files in directories (e.g., ../MNIST/trn_img/
# and /MNIST/trn_lab/).  Originally, when the code was written, it was for 5 fold
#cross validation and hence there were 5 files in each of the 
#directories.  Here, for illustration, we use only 1 training and 1 label
#file (e.g., '.../0_trn_img.txt' and '.../0_trn_lab.txt').
path = "C:/Users/antpc/Documents/saqib_smote/fmnist/"
path = "C:/Users/Research6/Desktop/smote experimentation/mnist/"
dtrnimg = (path+'/CBL_images')
dtrnlab = (path+'/CBL_labels')

ids = os.listdir(dtrnimg)
idtri_f = [os.path.join(dtrnimg, image_id) for image_id in ids]
print(idtri_f)

ids = os.listdir(dtrnlab)
idtrl_f = [os.path.join(dtrnlab, image_id) for image_id in ids]
print(idtrl_f)

#for i in range(5):
for i in range(len(ids)):
    print()
    print(i)
    encoder = Encoder(args)
    decoder = Decoder(args)

    device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
    print(device)
    decoder = decoder.to(device)
    encoder = encoder.to(device)

    train_on_gpu = torch.cuda.is_available()

    #decoder loss function
    criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    criterion = criterion.to(device)
    
    trnimgfile = idtri_f[i]
    trnlabfile = idtrl_f[i]
    
    print(trnimgfile)
    print(trnlabfile)
    dec_x = np.loadtxt(trnimgfile) 
    dec_y = np.loadtxt(trnlabfile)

    print('train imgs before reshape ',dec_x.shape) 
    print('train labels ',dec_y.shape) 
    print(collections.Counter(dec_y))
#     dec_x = dec_x.reshape(shape)
#     dec_x = dec_x.permute(0, 4 1, 2, 3)
#     dec_x = dec_x.reshape(shape[0],shape[3],shape[1],shape[2]) 
    print("shape >>>>>>>>>>>>>> ",)
    dec_x = dec_x.reshape(shape[0],3,32,32)
    print('train imgs after reshape ',dec_x.shape) 

    batch_size = 100
    num_workers = 0

    #torch.Tensor returns float so if want long then use torch.tensor
    tensor_x = torch.Tensor(dec_x)
    tensor_y = torch.tensor(dec_y,dtype=torch.long)
    mnist_bal = TensorDataset(tensor_x,tensor_y) 
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(mnist_bal, 
        batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True,num_workers=num_workers)
    
    

    best_loss = np.inf

    t0 = time.time()
    if args['train']:
        enc_optim = torch.optim.Adam(encoder.parameters(), lr = args['lr'])
        dec_optim = torch.optim.Adam(decoder.parameters(), lr = args['lr'])
    
        for epoch in range(args['epochs']):
            train_loss = 0.0
            tmse_loss = 0.0
            tdiscr_loss = 0.0
            # train for one epoch -- set nets to train mode
            encoder.train()
            decoder.train()
        
            for images,labs in train_loader:
            
                # zero gradients for each batch
                encoder.zero_grad()
                decoder.zero_grad()
                #print(images)
                images, labs = images.to(device), labs.to(device)
                #print('images ',images.size()) 
                labsn = labs.detach().cpu().numpy()
                #print('labsn ',labsn.shape, labsn)
            
                # run images
                z_hat = encoder(images)
            
                x_hat = decoder(z_hat) #decoder outputs tanh
                #print('xhat ', x_hat.size())
                #print(x_hat)
                mse = criterion(x_hat,images)
                #print('mse ',mse)
                
                       
                resx = []
                resy = []
            
                tc = np.random.choice(10,1)
                #tc = 9
                xbeg = dec_x[dec_y == tc]
                ybeg = dec_y[dec_y == tc] 
                xlen = len(xbeg)
                nsamp = min(xlen, 100)
                ind = np.random.choice(list(range(len(xbeg))),nsamp,replace=False)
                xclass = xbeg[ind]
                yclass = ybeg[ind]
            
                xclen = len(xclass)
                #print('xclen ',xclen)
                xcminus = np.arange(1,xclen)
                #print('minus ',xcminus.shape,xcminus)
                
                xcplus = np.append(xcminus,0)
                #print('xcplus ',xcplus)
                xcnew = (xclass[[xcplus],:])
                #xcnew = np.squeeze(xcnew)
                xcnew = xcnew.reshape(xcnew.shape[1],xcnew.shape[2],xcnew.shape[3],xcnew.shape[4])
                #print('xcnew ',xcnew.shape)
            
                xcnew = torch.Tensor(xcnew)
                xcnew = xcnew.to(device)
            
                #encode xclass to feature space
                xclass = torch.Tensor(xclass)
                xclass = xclass.to(device)
                xclass = encoder(xclass)
                #print('xclass ',xclass.shape) 
            
                xclass = xclass.detach().cpu().numpy()
            
                xc_enc = (xclass[[xcplus],:])
                xc_enc = np.squeeze(xc_enc)
                #print('xc enc ',xc_enc.shape)
            
                xc_enc = torch.Tensor(xc_enc)
                xc_enc = xc_enc.to(device)
                
                ximg = decoder(xc_enc)
                
                mse2 = criterion(ximg,xcnew)
            
                comb_loss = mse2 + mse
                comb_loss.backward()
            
                enc_optim.step()
                dec_optim.step()
            
                train_loss += comb_loss.item()*images.size(0)
                tmse_loss += mse.item()*images.size(0)
                tdiscr_loss += mse2.item()*images.size(0)
            
                 
            # print avg training statistics 
            train_loss = train_loss/len(train_loader)
            tmse_loss = tmse_loss/len(train_loader)
            tdiscr_loss = tdiscr_loss/len(train_loader)
            print('Epoch: {} \tTrain Loss: {:.6f} \tmse loss: {:.6f} \tmse2 loss: {:.6f}'.format(epoch,
                    train_loss,tmse_loss,tdiscr_loss))
            
        
        
            #store the best encoder and decoder models
            #here, /crs5 is a reference to 5 way cross validation, but is not
            #necessary for illustration purposes
            if train_loss < best_loss:
                print('Saving..')
#                 path_enc = "C:\\Users\\Research6\\Desktop\\smote"  + '\\bst_enc.pth'
#                 path_dec = "C:\\Users\\Research6\\Desktop\\smote"  + '\\bst_dec.pth'
                path_enc = path + '\\bst_enc.pth'
                path_dec = path + '\\bst_dec.pth'
                #    path_enc = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/smote/' \
                #     + str(i) + '/bst_enc.pth'
                # path_dec = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/smote/' \
                #     + str(i) + '/bst_dec.pth'
             
                torch.save(encoder.state_dict(), path_enc)
                torch.save(decoder.state_dict(), path_dec)
        
                best_loss = train_loss
        
        
        #in addition, store the final model (may not be the best) for
        #informational purposes
        path_enc = path + '\\f_enc.pth'
        path_dec = path  + '\\f_dec.pth'
        print(path_enc)
        print(path_dec)
        torch.save(encoder.state_dict(), path_enc)
        torch.save(decoder.state_dict(), path_dec)
        print()
              
    t1 = time.time()
    print('total time(min): {:.2f}'.format((t1 - t0)/60))             
 
t4 = time.time()
print('final time(min): {:.2f}'.format((t4 - t3)/60))
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue on pytorch, can you try to uncomment the following line below inside `nn.sequential()` of decoder.
#3d and 32 by 32.

```py
nn.Conv2d(self.dim_h * 4, self.dim_h * 8, 4, 1, 0, bias=False)
```